# Jest: react-router tests returns undefined 'params'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I'm trying to test a component with the `MemoryRouter` as indicated in the React-router docs with initial entries set so I can have params inside the wrapped component.

Component example :

```
render () {
  console.log(this.props.match.params.item)
}
```

In the App (works fine) :

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
      <Redirect to={`/${guessLocale()}`} />
    )} />
    <Route exact path='/:lang' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/:lang/:itemName' component={Vidactic} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

In the test (mount from Enzyme, match is undefined) :

```
mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/fr/pamp']}>
  <Vidactic />
</MemoryRouter>)
```

So I used this workaround but why initialEntries would not work by itself ?

```
mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/fr/pamp']}>
  <Vidactic match={{ params: { item: 'pamp' } }} />
</MemoryRouter>)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no `Route` in your test, so no matching will take place, and `this.props.match` will be undefined for `Vidactic`. Adding the route should make it work:

```
mount(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/fr/pamp']}>
    <Route exact path="/:lang/:itemName" component={Vidactic} />
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

To avoid duplicating the routes, you might want to put the `<Switch>..</Switch>` part in a separate component and use that in your tests.

Comment: I feel so incredibly dumb right now ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that your root component will no longer be `Vidactic`, but `MemoryRouter`. Apparently this can be circumvented with Enzyme's `mount` context (the second parameter for `mount()`), but this hasn't worked for me. However, since accessing the component is usually not necessary, this answer is completely fine.

Comment: You are awesome, Thank you